# Get parameter names collection from Java/Android url

Tags: java, android, url, parameters, uri

It's absolutely strange, but I can't find any Java/Android URL parser that will be compatible to return full list of parameters.

I've found java.net.URL and android.net.Uri but they are can't return parameters collection.

I want to pass url string, e.g.

```
String url = "http://s3.amazonaws.com/?AWSAccessKeyId=123&Policy=456&Signature=789&key=asdasd&Content-Type=text/plain&acl=public-read&success_action_status=201";

SomeBestUrlParser parser = new SomeBestUrlParser(url);
String[] parameters = parser.getParameterNames();
// should prints array with following elements
// AWSAccessKeyId, Policy, Signature, key, Content-Type, acl, success_action_status
```

Does anyone know ready solution?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is way to get collection of all parameter names.

```
String url = "http://domain.com/page?parameter1=value1&parameter2=value2";
List<NameValuePair> parameters = URLEncodedUtils.parse(new URI(url));
for (NameValuePair p : parameters) {
    System.out.println(p.getName());
    System.out.println(p.getValue());
}
```

Comment: I am getting compile time error: The method parse(HttpEntity) in the type URLEncodedUtils is not applicable for the arguments (URI).

Comment: NameValuePair is depreciated then what we use??

Answer (score 4):

This static method builds map of parameters from given URL

> ```
> private Map<String, String> extractParamsFromURL(final String url) throws URISyntaxException {
>     return new HashMap<String, String>() {{
>         for(NameValuePair p : URLEncodedUtils.parse(new URI(url), "UTF-8")) 
>             put(p.getName(), p.getValue());
>     }};
> }
> ```

usage

> extractParamsFromURL(url).get("key")

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [URLEncodedUtils](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/utils/URLEncodedUtils.html)

Answer (score 0):

UrlQuerySanitizer added in API level 1

```
        UrlQuerySanitizer sanitizer = new UrlQuerySanitizer(url_string);
        List<UrlQuerySanitizer.ParameterValuePair> list =  sanitizer.getParameterList();
        for (UrlQuerySanitizer.ParameterValuePair pair : list) {
            System.out.println(pair.mParameter);
            System.out.println(pair.mValue);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The [urllib](https://github.com/EricEdens/urllib) library will parse the query string parameters and allow you to access the params as either a list or a map. Use the list if there might be duplicate keys, otherwise the map is pretty handy.

Given this snippet:

```
String raw = "http://s3.amazonaws.com/?AWSAccessKeyId=123&Policy=456&Signature=789&key=asdasd&Content-Type=text/plain&acl=public-read&success_action_status=201";
Url url = Url.parse(raw);
System.out.println(url.query().asMap());
for (KeyValue param : url.query().params()) {
  System.out.println(param.key() + "=" + param.value());
}
```

The output is:

```
{Policy=456, success_action_status=201, Signature=789, AWSAccessKeyId=123, acl=public-read, key=asdasd, Content-Type=text/plain}
AWSAccessKeyId=123
Policy=456
Signature=789
key=asdasd
Content-Type=text/plain
acl=public-read
success_action_status=201
```