# Starting android app on click dynamic link in email

Tags: android, email, http, android-activity, dynamic-url

I need to start an app from email using link (which contain some parameter) for example
http://www.this-so-does-not-exist.com/something

I am able to start my app after click a simple email using following in intent-filter.

```
<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>

            <data
                android:host="www.this-so-does-not-exist.com/something"
                android:scheme="http"/>
        </intent-filter>
```

now i want to pass some information along with email link like
http://www.this-so-does-not-exist.com/something?id=4545

how i can read this from my android app.

any help will be much appreciated. thanks in advance.

Comment: Try this for Read Data from Incoming Intents.

Intent intent = getIntent(); 
String action = intent.getAction();
Uri data = intent.getData();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getIntent().getData()` from  your `Activity` will give you the `Uri` that was used to launch your app. Query parameters are available from a variety of methods on `Uri`, [such as `getQueryParameter()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html#getQueryParameter(java.lang.String)).

Answer (score 0):

[Taken from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12728084/get-parameter-names-collection-from-java-android-url), we get the intent string and then parse the URL like follows.

```
if(getIntent() != null){
    String url = getIntent().getDataString(); // should be http://www.this-so-does-not-exist.com/something?id=4545
    List<NameValuePair> parameters = URLEncodedUtils.parse(new URI(url));
    for (NameValuePair p : parameters) {
        Log.i("MyApp", "Parameter Name: " + p.getName() + ", Parameter Value: " + p.getValue();
    }
}
```

Using this, you can add as many parameters as you want to your URL and easily retrieve them for usage.